# animating multiple divs according to slides on a animated slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a script like in this [Website](http://www.booking.com/hotel/in/vellara.en-gb.html?aid=357026;label=gog235jc-hotel-XX-in-vellara-unspec-in-com-L%3Aen-O%3Aunkos-B%3Achrome-N%3AXX-S%3Abo-U%3AXX;sid=6c8a4d4ad7bec2f2365800d0e848904d;dist=0&sb_price_type=total&type=total&)

where divs appears according to the scrolling.

PS: Need this without mouse click or hover events.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JQuery for that without click event

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 200 && y < 600) {
    $('.magic').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.magic').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 4000px;
}
.magic {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>this is a simple page keep scrolling... </p>
<div class="magic"></div>
<div class="otherdiv"></div>
```

Comment: no, my requirement is like the when the slider changes to next, the review panel in the right side of the above website changes.

Comment: what do you mean by the panel changes

Comment: i meant review div